# Combine multiple Replace expressions for a SSIS Derived Column

Tags: ssis, expression, derived-column

I have 3 Replace expressions that resolve in SSIS derived columns. When I attempt to combine them into 1 string they error. The replace are all in the same column. Immediately below are the 3 resolved expressions.

```
    REPLACE([Column1],"&#58;",":")

    REPLACE([Column1],"\n"," ")

    REPLACE([Column1],"</div>"," ")
```

Below are the 2 unresolved expressions I have attempted.

```
    REPLACE([Column1],"&#58;",":","\n"," ","</div>"," ")

    Replace(Replace([Column1],"&#58;",":"),"\n"," "),"</div>"," ")
```

Any assistance in getting the correct syntax is greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you show me error ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This will replace your [Column1] with all your values.

```
REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE([nightrate],"&#58;",":"),"\n"," "),"</div>"," ")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for catching the additional Replace I neglected to add.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
(REPLACE([COURSE_CODE],"&#58;",":"))+REPLACE([COURSE_CODE],"\n"," ")+REPLACE([COURSE_CODE],"</div>"," ")
```

Answer (score 0):

Check This.

`\` is escape character. If you want to have single backslash literal inside SSIS string you have to escape it and use `\\`

Code :

```
REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE([Column1],"</div>",":"),"&#58;",":"),"\\n"," ")
```

in your code you missed 3rd replace function.

> Code:

[image]

> Output :

[image]